# Antenna inductance calculation (RFID applications, inductive coupling)

Tags: inductance, rfid, inductive, coupling

Inductance of various antenna coils of different shapes can be estimated. Some examples  are:

- A circular coil with single turn.
- N turn multilayer circular coil.
- Spiral coil.
- N turn squae loop coil.
- etc.

However, is it possible to estimate the inductance cooil of a 3D shaped coil? i.e, imagine a loop wire that runs along some of the edges of a cube doing several turns. I could not find any reference regarding this. I am trying to build different shape antennas for RFID low frequency devices (inductive coupling).

Reference: [Antenna Circuit Design for RFID Applications. Microchip. Author: Youbok Lee.](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00710c.pdf)

Comment: 2D spiral shapes and Zo are easy , 3D shapes desired to be isometric are hard and require Comsol or Ansys or other antenna software design EM experience.  Diversity and gain are known tradeoffs.

Comment: @Tony Stewart EE75 thank you for your answer. I understand what you mean, actually I considered Ansys but my intention is just for very specific and simple 3D shapes, e.g., the square loop shape where the sides are bent 90 degrees (and then you get like the lid of a box). I'd like to get a set of equations that allow the estimation of the inductance, which is the only parameter I am interested for now. Looking for some references.